# Angular 2 *ngFor only supports to add 10 elements at a time in inline template

Tags: angular, ngfor

I wanted to repeat particular element several amount of time, so I'm using `*ngFor` directive with hardcoded array like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and that got worked awesome. I achieved what I wanted to do.

**Code**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>My First Angular App</h1>
      <div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
          {{item}}: My Element 
      </div>`
})
```

[Demo Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OkZuGi00ExfDQ7FE3DhN?p=preview)

But as soon as I increased the array size more than 10, I start getting below error. Which is really annoying.

> zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:355 Unhandled Promise rejection:
>   Unsupported number of argument for pure functions: 11 ; Zone:  ;
>   Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Unsupported number of argument for
>   pure functions: 11(…) Error: Unsupported number of argument for pure
>   functions: 11

**Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]">
  {{item}}
</div>`
```

I'm curious to know why that error is happening as soon as array size increase more than 10? But another interesting thing is when I put the same array in component inside variable `items= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]` and used `items` in `*ngFor` and it got worked.

Is there any reason behind such special case? Parden me if I missing something simple/silly.

[Problem Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxIEoXEr0F3ORJuKw61u?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting a hard time to achieve this task http://stackoverflow.com/a/41039141/3297613 . Here is the demo plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/B5ucnBONC55WTR3VnFBr?p=preview . My app have a common service but I don't know how to create an observable on that common service and make all the other services to subscribe to that particular observable. I just want to clear all the service data once the user gets logged out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a limitation of the Angular2 template parser to avoid complexity in the parser (by design). It's usually a good idea to keep data in the component instance anyway.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d972d8235458a6e65819f96ee56da059ec76321b/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/util.ts#L82

Comment: can I get any reference which is mentioning the same thing, why the number is 10 only?

Comment: I guess I got this working in beta version, may be team have refactored something & broke something :p

Comment: it shouldn't be, because we don't have Pipe on my expression. It can be the case that `*ngFor` is implicitly doing something

Comment: ok, I'll wait for 1 more hour and then I'll log this issue on github page :)

Comment: I just was a bit sloppy reading the information you provided. I think my initial answer still holds - as designed.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d972d8235458a6e65819f96ee56da059ec76321b/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/identifiers.ts#L191